# ランダムで取り出した値から画像を表示する(PHP)

Tags: php, array

ランダムで取り出したトランプの模様と数字が特定の値であった際に画像を表示するロジックを組みたいのですが、下記だとエラーがでてしまいます。

原因は一体どこにあるのでしょうか。ちなみに画像パスは正しいです。
（例えばハートの4がランダムで出た場合、ハートの4の画像をimage/pngディレクトリ内のh04.pngを呼び出すのがゴールです。）

```
<?php
//カードを作成
$cards = array();
$marks = array("clover","heart","diamond","spade");

for($mark=0;$mark<4;$mark++){
    for($num=1;$num<=13;$num++){
        array_push($cards, array($marks[$mark] => "$num"));
    }
}   

$rnd = array_map(
    function($i) use($cards){
        return $cards[$i];
    },
    array_rand($cards,5));

if($cards == "[heart]" => "4"){
        echo "image/png/h04.png"; 
    }
```

Comment: 出ているエラーの内容を書いて欲しいです。

Comment: ハートの 4 が含まれているのかどうかだけをチェックしたいのであれば、`if (in_array(["heart" => "4"], $rnd)) { echo "image/png/h04.png"; }` でもよいかと思います。

Comment: ランダムに**5つ**取り出していることは理解されていますか？その中に含まれていれば出力するということならmetropolisさんのコメントのような方法になりますし、ランダムに5つ取り出した順番どおりに出力したいならforeachなどで順番に処理する必要があるかと思いますが、どちらなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if($cards == "[heart]" => "4"){`

この箇所で構文エラーが出ますね。
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in test.php on line 18

この行を、metropolisさんが言われているようなコードに修正すれば良いかと思います。